# Same side drop links from different company, will it make any difference?

Tags: honda, civic, suspension

I'm just about to change my sway bar drop links.  3 out of 4 parts are from one company and one of the rear is from a different company.

On any normal car I wouldn't even ask but it's a civic vti 1999 and it's meant to be good at going around corners fast. The parts do feel slightly different but I can't describe in what way but both companies(megaquip and blueprint) have a good reputation for aftermarket oe products.

Should I ensure both links on each side are from the same company or will it not really make any difference?  I know one might wear before the other if some difference in quality but I'm not concerned about that, I'm asking more about handling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the drop links on your car have ball-joints in them - I'd be more concerned if they were bushes, as you're more likely to get a variance in a bush (e.g. the hardness/stiffness of the rubber/poly) than you are in a balljoint.

Therefore I think it will be fine, though personally I'd want them the same on each axle, just for consistency!